# @font-face is not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I have a CSS file in `/css` and fonts in `/images`. My CSS code uses `@font-face`, and it works in IE8, IE9, and all the decent browsers, but obviously not in IE7.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
    src: url('../image/chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../image/chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url(../images/chunkfive.woff) format('woff'), url(../images/chunkfive-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'), url(../images/chunkfive-webfont.svg) format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: ChunkFiveRegular, Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Why does the text still show up set as Georgia?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the page?

Comment: If your fonts are in `/images`, you need to use `/images`, not `/image`. Also, `'eot'` should work better than `'embedded-opentype'`. That said, your fonts belong in `/css`; fonts are not images.

Comment: @PointedEars that was the problem. Mind to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fonts are in `/images`, you need to use `/images`, not `/image`.  That said, your fonts belong in `/css`; fonts are not images.

Also, according to [Paul Irish's article](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/), `'eot'` should work better than `'embedded-opentype'` (untested).

Comment: Using 'eot' or '☺' causes IE9 to ignore the EOT and use the WOFF instead. I've found that in most cases a compressed EOT is actually smaller than a WOFF and therefore preferable.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_fontface/

```
@font-face {
font-family:InYourFace;
src: url('Ubuntu-B.eot');
// this smile and ? fix your problem
// because IE don't wanl load local font without this hack
src: url('Ubuntu-B.eot?') format('☺'),  
    url('Ubuntu-B.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Ubuntu-B.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Ubuntu-B.svg#webfontssbCkuz5') format('svg');
}
```